# STL containers: iterating between two iterators

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I am storing values in a std::map

I am finding two values in the map, and I want to iterate between the first through to the last item - however the <= operator is not implemented, so I can't do somethimng like this:

```
    void foobar(const DatedRecordset& recs, const double startstamp, const double endtstamp)
    {
        DatedRecordsetConstIter start_iter = recs.lower_bound(startstamp), end_iter = recs.lower_bound(endtstamp);

        // Can't do this .... (<= not defined)
        //for (DatedRecordsetConstIter cit = start_iter; cit <= end_iter; cit++ )

        / So have to resort to a hack like this:
        for (DatedRecordsetConstIter cit = start_iter; cit != recs.end(); cit++ ) {
            if ((*cit).first <= (*end_iter).first){
               //do something;
            }
            else
               break;
            }
       }
}
```

Is there a more elegant way of iterating between two known iterators?

Comment: You can use cit != (end_iter + 1).

Comment: That will not work for an `std::map<T>::iterator`; it doesn't have a `+` operator defined.  Using something like `boost::next` would work, though, assuming that `end_iter` is not `recs.end()` (the original specification would be invalid in that case, though, anyway).

Comment: @Jeremiah Willcock: You are right, but the `++` operator can do the trick `new_end_iter = end_iter++`.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want `++end_iter`?  You want the next iterator after `end_iter` to be the `!=` bound on the loop.

Comment: @Jeremiah Willcock: Yes exactly, thank you for the note, I corrected my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `!=` instead of `<=` and it will do what you want it to do.

```
void foobar(const DatedRecordset& recs, const double startstamp, const double endtstamp)
{
    DatedRecordsetConstIter start_iter = recs.lower_bound(startstamp),
                            end_iter = recs.upper_bound(endtstamp);

    for (DatedRecordsetConstIter cit = start_iter; cit != end_iter; ++cit) {
    }
}
```

Comment: This has an off-by-one problem relative to the original code: in this version, `cit` will never be equal to `end_iter` within the loop, while the original code has `cit == end_iter` in the last iteration because of the use of `<=`.

Comment: I think using `upper_bound` to compute `end_iter` will do the trick.

Comment: @Jeremiah That is true. I changed `end_iter` to use `upper_bound` per @Mark.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a `<=` operator for `std::map<>::iterator`, but using `!=` on `end_iter` should do basically the same thing.  If you want to include the end iterator itself in the iteration, use something like a `do` loop to do the `!=` test at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct ManipulateMatchingPairs {
    template<class K, class V>
    void operator()(const std::pair<K,V>& p) const {
        // do with p.second as you please here.
    }
};

// ...
std::for_each(start_iter, end_iter, ManipulateMatchingPairs());
```

Comment: The mapped type can be written in code: `DatedRecordset::mapped_type` . But I think this approach misses any item(s) (if a `multimap`) equal to the `end_iter`.

Comment: I'm not following you. The `end_iter` always points at one-past-the-last-element.

Answer (score 0):

The STL [for_each](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) algorithm also will not include the ending iterator in the loop. You could always increcment end_iter and just use for_each so that it will be included, though.

```
 void foobar(const DatedRecordset& recs, 
             const double startstamp, 
             const double endtstamp)
{
    DatedRecordsetConstIter start_iter = recs.lower_bound(startstamp);
    DatedRecordsetConstIter end_iter = recs.lower_bound(endtstamp);
    if(end_iter != recs.end())
      ++end_iter;

    for_each(start_iter, end_iter, []()
       {
           //do something inside the lambda.
       });
}
```

Something like that maybe? I didn't give it a compile check ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `!=` operator. I believe this is because a std::map isn't necessarily contiguous in memory (so the `<=` operator wouldn't make much sense, whereas a `std::vector` would), I could be wrong though

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the end iterator in the loop, you can increment your end-condition iterator `++end_iter`. After that the loop with `cit != end_iter` does the same as you intend to do with `cit <= end_iter` before incrementing.